# Broadcast receiver, check status, turning off connection with F8

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver

I am using eclipse with `android sdk 3.2`
I have some problems to make my broadcast receiver working when the `connection is lost`.

first I have checked the type of network to make sure I understand well :

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .isConnectedOrConnecting();
            boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                    .isConnectedOrConnecting();

            NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info.getTypeName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pas de connexion",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (!is3g)
                Log.i("Network Listener", "DISCONNECTED");
            else
                Log.i("Network Listener", "CONNECTED");
```

==> this is a mobile network, I'm connected

Then I press F8 or I make :

```
telnet localhost 5554
gsm data off
```

to stop the connection

Here is my `dynamic broadcast receiver` in an activity :

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity { 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.query);
this.registerReceiver(this.networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(
     ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

}


BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
//i have tried several things : State networkState = networkInfo.getState();
// if (networkState.compareTo(State.DISCONNECTED) == 0) ...
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECTED",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   Log.i("Network Listener", "Connected");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DISCONNECTED",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("Network Listener", "Network Type Changed");
            Intent offline = new Intent(AccountInfoActivity.this,
                    OfflineWorkService.class);
            startService(offline);
        }


};
```

My manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The problem is : when the activityA is launched, my broadcast receive something and it displays "Connected"(Log) and my toast. When I turn off the connection manually, nothing happend. My service is not started, log message are not displayed, only toast messages work ...

And even better, when I turn on the connection again (`by pressing F8`), I test again the type of connection, Toast messages are shown but this time Log messages don't work.
Problems happend when I press F8. Anyway, I think I miss something with broadcast receivers, it's not totally clear.

Please help me.

Comment: A little bit late, but i tried it on my tab and it works. Maybe a bug of the emulator